# Macro to change date criteria1 within macro

Tags: vba, excel

With the code I have below, this is a few lines from the whole macro, but I need to be able to change the date `criteria1` easily without having to manually do it each time. This is on a monthly report worksheet. The format of the date is generated from a data-collecting database and cannot be changed.

Does code exist to be able to change a macro, a line in a macro, by using a macro, specifically the date I have in my example?

```
Sheets("Raw Data 3M").Select
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$1000").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
    "=2015       -10-October"
    Range("A1:I5000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Raw Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: This months data is 2015     -10-October, the next month will be, 2015    -11-November, and so on and so forth. Id like to exchange the later month code with the older month. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Is there a pattern to the dates?

Comment: The only way I can think to answer that would be... yes... I use these worksheets once a month. The month im in, for instance this one, would be shown as 2015-10-October. Next month would be 2015-11-November. I have multiple macros to do similar functions with different worksheets. Instead of manually changing the October to a November, I would like a macro to do it for me... Thought?

Comment: What is the pattern? Something like the third Thursday of each month? or something like that.  Because if there is a pattern set your date as a variable that follows the pattern.

Comment: Sorry for the edit within an edit. I hit the return button to quick... the data could be run randomly every month. could be Friday the 10th of the month, or Thursday the 23rd of the month...

Comment: Completely random is what I mean

Comment: @Inglis if I uderstood, you want to replace the hardcoded date with the date of the moment, formatted in the same way as `2015-10-October`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Inglis,

There are several ways to do this.

If you want the quickest way that I wouldn't recommend distributing, (because users can be dumb), just set the autofilter conditions to an inputbox:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$1000").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
inputbox("Prompt","Title","=2015       -10-October")
```

Just replace *Prompt* and *Title* with something more appropriate.

You could also have an inputbox that formats the date entered as required, but if you don't follow a particular format, the code will error out. Such as:

```
Dim vDate as Variant
vDate = inputbox("Type a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy")
vDate = DateSerial(Mid(vDate, 7, 4), Mid(vDate, 4, 2), Mid(vDate, 1, 2))
vDate = "=" & Format(vDate, "yyyy       -dd-mmmm")
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$1000").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=vDate
```

Hope this helps!